# Is AllowZeroLength for Number column in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to know that Can we create the column to allow null values even if it has default value as 0 in MS Access?

Comment: If we dont set the defaultvalue to Zero for Number Type coulmn.Then will it allow nulls?Any Reference link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. If it is not a required entry -- that is, the Required property is set to No -- it will allow null. It will be up to you or the user to clear the 0 where you want a null.

Comment: Like we have AllowZeroLength property for Text,Memo etc Do we have Property like that?Suppose If we migrate the DB to SQL SERVER the column property having Number Data Type will be converted to int (AllowNulls,DefaultValue-0) Right?

Comment: On a straight export from Access to SQL Server, I do not get the default value.

Comment: Is null is acceptable for the number Column having Default value '0'?

Comment: Yes, I said that it was as long as you have not set required property.